# Attempting to convert XPS to PDF Documents using Aspose.pdf

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, pdf-conversion, aspose.pdf

I am trying to convert XPS document to a PDF document.I am able to convert some simple XPS documents but not heavy ones. I have taken a free developer license for Aspose. This is a snippet from my code which is dealing with this conversion

```
Aspose.Pdf.License pdfLicense = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
pdfLicense.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");

Aspose.Pdf.XpsLoadOptions options = new XpsLoadOptions();
Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(filepath, options);         
string newfullpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath) + ".pdf";       

document.Save(newfullpath);
```

**ERROR**

> Unhandled Exception: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security
>   transpare nt method
>   'Aspose.Pal.PalBitmap.ParseRgb(System.Drawing.Imaging.Bitmap‌​Data,
>   Bool ean)' to access security critical method
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal .Copy(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32,
>   Int32)' failed

Comment: I am getting this error ---Unhandled Exception: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transpare
nt method 'Aspose.Pal.PalBitmap.ParseRgb(System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData, Bool
ean)' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
.Copy(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)' failed.

Comment: Edit your question and add the error detail there rather then writing in comment.